# What are Design pattern headings?

Tags: design-patterns, uml

Could someone kindly explain what are design pattern headings in UML? Most of the information I can find is too complex for beginners.

Comment: I am not sure "design pattern heading" is a widely adopted term.. What do you mean exactly? Can you link to some of the information you would like to have clarified?

Comment: @petrk. Here's the question: "Give four headings for documenting a design pattern."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you are looking for, but the classic Gang of Four patterns are most often documented according to a certain template, breaking down the pattern description into sections.

It describes the pattern as a whole, motivation behind the pattern. Then a more detailed information follows, describing the participants, variations, consequences, known usages in real systems and so on.

See: [Gang of Four Template](http://hillside.net/gang-of-four-template), [How do I document a design pattern?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1223)

Comment: Thank you, that helped clarify that these damned "design pattern headings" are nothing more than templates used to describe a design pattern.

Comment: I'd rather say that the headings you refer to correspond to the template sections.